# Perl failed locales. How do you set it?

Tags: perl, locale

I am getting the following whenever I try and run perl on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "en_GB.UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
```

I've tried running "dpkg-reconfigure locales" but nothing seems to work.  How can I setup my locales on 18.04?

Comment: have you installed the locale packages manually?

Comment: No, this is a clean install of 18.04

Comment: There are packages for them. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/locales. Try to install them.

Comment: I've already done "sudo apt-get install locales".

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/locales-all is the correct package (grep for `en_GB.utf8` in [filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/locales-all/filelist)), `locales` contains only directories.

Comment: I just did a quick google @daxim. Didn't actually check in detail.

Comment: When you ran `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, did you make sure that both `en_GB.UTF-8` and `en_US.UTF-8` are selected/generated?

Comment: @haukex, I have no idea how I missed that. That worked, cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have the following to select a locale to use, based on what is available.

```
# Insure the "locale" is set for unicode handling
#
for LANG in en_AU.UTF-8 en_GB.UTF-8 C.UTF-8 C; do
  if locale -a 2>/dev/null | grep -q "$LANG"; then
    export LANG
    break
  fi
done
export LC_COLLATE=C     # make 'ls' sort as 'C' order not locale order
```

I had to do this a Minimal Debian Docker Containers, which has minimal locales defined.  Probably similar to Ubuntu.
On those containers the above falls back to 'C.UTF-8' (only C.UTF-8, C, and POSIX is actually available).

I do not set a LC_ALL or LC_CTYPE